# Make windows server forward DNS queries to another server on the AD zone

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm currently facing an issue with Windows Server which I can't figure out how to solve. Let me please explain the setup first:

We have a main, authoritative DNS server running on a linux machine, let's call it **Tux**. This server is authoritative for the zone myorganization.tld.
Now, I've recently added a Windows Server machine (we'll call it **Gates**) to act as a domain controller for myorganization.tld, so a DNS server had to be set up on it as well.

Now, clients I want to join to the domain have to use **Gates** as the main DNS server. However, only **Tux** knows where most subdomains of myorganization.tld are, and manually copying them is not an option. **Gates** refuses to ask **Tux** for the subdomains he doesn't know. It does ask him for "external" domains (anything outside the myorganization.tld zone).

How can I make **Gates** contact **Tux** for the names belonging to this zone too?

---

#### Things I've already tried

- Add **Tux** as a NS record in **Gates**' myorganization.tld zone.
- Set **Tux** as the SOA in **Gates**' myorganization.tld zone.
- Add a wildcard (*) domain and delegate it to **Tux**. (This seems to work for individual names, tho. But honestly is a pain adding them one by one, and almost just as bad as copying them).

---

#### Things I'd like to avoid

- Having DNS record manually replicated on both machines.
- Making **Gates** the main DNS server of my network (DNS is used on tons of more subnets other than the domain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it the way you want. As long as Windows DNS server sees itself auhoritative for the zone, it won't ask anywhere else. And, your clients will not look for the missing records in Tux, even if you tell them to use it as secondary.

If Tux support dynamic updates, you can use it as your primary DNS server for Active Directory as well. [Like this](http://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/network-services/using-linux-bind-dns-servers-for-active-directory-domains/)

You should've used a subdomain for your AD domain name. Consider it, if it's not too late.

Comment: Just what I supposed... I'll change the domain name then, there aren't many PCs on the domain yet. Thanks!